# What's the best source to learn deep learning with?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I am learning image process with OpenCV (Python). I want to extend my image processing with **deep learning** for **image recognition** and other stuff, but I don't know **where to start**.

When I google it, it says to learn convolutional neural networsk first, for that do I have to learn neural network first or is there any other source to learn deep-learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would at least consider [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/).  Although it is not designed specifically for image processing, their tutorials are very, very well done.  Here is a [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/image_recognition) to a tutorial for image recognition, but I recommend looking around at other tutorials.  It's a perfect pair for python as well.  Hope I helped.

P.S. I recommend tags more specific to your question.  Maybe "opencv" or "image-recognition".

Comment: Please refrain from answering blatantly off-topic questions, as suggested in the community guidelines - see [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) and [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)

Comment: Isn't it better to answer it along with tips to make it better?  I feel like people will just stop using the platform altogether if we don't provide an answer.  I totally understand your reasoning, I just feel guilty.

Comment: If you see the rationale in the linked guidelines, it is exactly the opposite: answering off-topic questions by whatever means (even by comments) simply encourages people to keep on coming for more (off topic questions)... for good or bad, SO doesn't suffer from lack of users - it does however suffer from questions of very low quality, which in turn discourages serious respondents. SO is *specifically* about *programming/coding* questions, not about ones that can be posted in Quora & Reddit (let alone ones that are simply a matter of googling)...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. @desertnaut